# Using KL divergence to select topic from LDA

Tags: python, scikit-learn, kullback-leibler, topic-models, latent-dirichlet-alloc

I have used sklearn's [sklearn.decomposition.LatentDirichletAllocation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.LatentDirichletAllocation.html) module to model 10 topics in a set of documents.

I have also used the same on a reference text (1 document) and obtained a 1 topic LDA for it.

I want to compare the 10 topics from the documents to the 1 reference topic and determine which one is most closely related to the reference.

I have been trying to figure out an implementation of KL divergence for this purpose but cannot seem to understand how to tie it in with the LDA outputs. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: "I have also used the same on a reference text (1 document) and obtained a 1 topic LDA for it." For a single document, what would constitute a solution to the topic modelling problem? As I understand what topic modelling is, it requires at least two documents. If I ignore the quoted sentence and try to understand what you might want to do, I think you have predicted the topic distribution in the document you call a "reference text", and then you like to derive which of documents in your training data is most similar to the reference text using KL divergence. Have I understood you correctly?

Comment: @HansEkbrand sorry for the late reply, yes your understanding is correct. I was able to get this working by getting the Dirichlet distributions for the reference text and comparing it to the distributions from my LDA topics by computing the KL divergence for each topic against the reference.